# How to print value of void pointer if its a structure member

Tags: c

Here I have a structure with name `param` and a structure member is `void` pointer now I want to `print` the value of `void` pointer in hex for 500 times.

```
struct param
{
   void * tc_data;
}
param_t param_data;

UINT32 temp_index2=0;
UINT32 *pc = (UINT32*)param_data.tc_data;
for (temp_index2 =0;temp_index2<500;temp_index2++)
{ 
   printf (" DATA =%x\n", pc[temp_index2]);
}
```

The way I am, its `print` only address but I want to `print` the value. Any help with explanation would be great.

Comment: From the code that you have added in your question. tc_data is pointing to junk data.

Comment: How did you conclude that your program prints only addresses? Please post a [mcve], the input to the program, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: according to my code its pointing to junk data lets say param_data.tc_data has valid data now i need to print the values

Comment: tc_data is an uninitialized pointer as pointed out earlier and also array index temp_index2 is out of bounds as param_data is not an array but a single struct.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to use the `%p` specifier for pointers.

Comment: "according to my code its pointing to junk data lets say param_data.tc_data has valid data": please amend your example to include those valid data.

Comment: The print loop looks ok. If it is printing junk then it's because the pointer is pointing to a memory area with junk data in it. Look over how data is assigned and make sure the pointer points to correct data.

Answer (score 0):

May you are having confusion with hex and decimal data. You are printing data in hex and assuming that is the address. If you want to see in decimal do:

```
printf (" DATA =%d\n", pc[temp_index2]);
```